# Macro should export only 2 columns from each query and paste all in one sheet (sheet1)

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

Below code is exporting queries in 3 different tabs and also changes the tab name which o don't want. However, I want all 3 queries to be pasted in sheet 1 and only columns from all queries show paste in sheet one please help. I am not able to give the column name that I want to export from each query...
AGP, CBC & qdAGC are queries name.. Pease help I want only 2 columns from each query to be exported in 1 sheet i.e. sheet1

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit


Private Sub Command0_Click()
ExportToExcel
End Sub

Public Sub ExportToExcel()
  
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "AGP", "C:\path.xlsx", True

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "CBC", "C:\path.xlsx", True

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "qdAGC", "C:\path .xlsx", True



End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a **UNION query** from your base queries, that contains exactly the columns & rows that you want to export.

Then `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet` that UNION query.

e.g.

```sql
SELECT foo AS col1, bar AS col2
FROM AGP

UNION ALL

SELECT floo AS col1, stuff AS col2
FROM CBC
```

etc.

Comment: Perfect I got it!!! Thank you. I am new to Macros/VBA/Access... However, could you please also help me in coding, to export the desired columns in the code that I have pasted. The code what I pasted export entire data to excel, but I want only the first 2 columns from the query! could you please help me coding that it would really help me....

Comment: I did and getting the output also. But in the output, other columns are also visible which I don't want...  other tables are also in view which I don't want.. only the 2 columns which mentioned in SQL
SELECT AGC.County,  AGC.[Over Votes], *FROM AGC
UNION ALL 
SELECT CBC.County, CBC.[Over Votes], *FROM CBC